# Counting Sort for a set

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, counting, counting-sort

Hello i know how couting sort works, how to implement it, But is it possible to implement it on a class who got 3 attributs and need to countSort the whole DisjointSet on a specific attribut.

If so, lets say i have this class:

```
class myStructure {
public:
    int m_id = -1;
    myStructure* m_parent = NULL;
    int m_sortie = -1;
    int m_echeance = -1;

    myStructure() {}

    myStructure(int id, myStructure* parent, int sortie, int echeance)
        : m_id(id), m_parent(parent), m_sortie(sortie), m_echeance(echeance)
    { }
};
```

How can i implement the counting sort on the m_echance.
Thanks

Comment: Counting sort just need an attribute to sort, Here in your class all attributes are public so you can get it to sort. So what is the problem, Explain in Details , You Need Code or Something else

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can apply counting sort.
It is applicable to any field which can be mapped with integers. In general counting sort should be used if the range of values(in your case m_echeance) is small.
Below is high level approach to do that-

Let's say your objects are stored in array A[]

range of m_echeance is [0,R-1]

1. Make a count array.
2. loop through the array A to count frequencies of the objects with different m_echeance values.

something like count[A[i]->m_echeance + 1]++;

3. Get the cumulative frequencies for the count array.
4. Copy objects in auxiliary array  based on cumulative frequencies.
5. Copy back objects from auxiliary array to original array.

Hope it helps!